# Accessing Access over JDBC (using ODBC?)

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I'm looking for a way to open an Access MDB file inside a Java App (using JDBC).

A quick Google Search suggests that I need the JDBC-ODBC Bridge for this...

Does this mean that I need to configure every system I want to run my app on to provide a ODBC DSN for the MDB I want to open?

And one more question (since I've never used ODBC before): will the communication happen over some sort of a socket (in a client/server-style), or through method/function calls (like with an embeded Derby db)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You won't need to configure every system with a SYSTEM or USER ODBC DSN to access the MDB you want. You can still provide all the information you need in your JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:/yourdb.mdb
```

But keep in mind that the system **will** need to have the driver you are using installed.

2) The communication will happen the way your ODBC driver communicates. If it opens a socket to the server (the way an Oracle ODBC connection takes place) it will open a socket. If it uses library function calls, it will communicate through library function calls.

JDBC to ODBC communication uses JNI to communicate.

Comment: I guess you could have a JDBC proxy driver. That is to say a JDBC driver that connects over a socket to another Java process which then executes the calls on a real JDBC driver (JDBC-ODBC bridge). I think such things exist for JDBC, OBDC and UDBC.

Comment: @Buttercup: The specific code I posted is Windows only. But you can still use JDBC-ODBC bridge under Linux (provided you have ODBC installed, of course).

Comment: @Tin Hawtin: I think what you are referring to are JDBC Type 3 (middleware) drivers.