# Read a MS Access database without OBDC driver

Tags: java, database, ms-access, 64-bit

I've run into a very annoying problem while trying to update some code. The code in question reads some (a lot actually) of info from a local MS access file (*.mdb), and then perform several operations on this data (just simple stuff). Keep in mind that I only need to read the db, nothing more.

The problem is that I'm triying to deploy this program to work in x64 operating systems (win7 mostly) and I can't access the 32-bit ODBC driver.

This is the part of the code that access the db, the variavle "path" is a string that contains the absolute path to the mdb file, as I said, this file is local.

```
public void openConection()
{
    try
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put ("charSet", "ISO-8859-1");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft AccessDriver (*.mdb)};DBQ=";
        dbURL += this.path + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=false)";
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft AccessDriver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + this.path, props);
        this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Success");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
            System.out.println("Error :" + e);
    }
}
```

This throws the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The problem (as far as I can tell) is in this piece of code:

```
("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft AccessDriver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + this.path, props
```

If I'm correct, this tries to bridge the java jdbc to MS Access ODBC, which is a 32 bit driver and therefore not accesible by the program. I tried googling my problem, but didn't find anything that could help, I did find a 64-bit MS Access driver, but it required uninstalling the 32-bit version of Office.

Also, I'd like to avoid having to create a DSN for this, as this program has to be given to a lot of people who would not know how to do that.

Thanks.

Zegpi

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818491/is-there-a-64bit-driver-for-microsoft-access?

Comment: Just run your program with a 32bit Java VM. That will be able to access the 32bit ODBC drivers.

Comment: Remou, I can't use the drivers as they require me to uninstall the 32-bit version of office, which I can't do.

a_horse_with_no_name, I coudn't find a way to make netbeans to run in 32-bit, I even reinstalled everything using the 32-bit version of JDK, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to read directly from the file using a Java API. There are several libraries out there.

You could try out [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/). It's free.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, will try it as soon as I can. Thank you. I'll let you know (and accept the answer) as soon as I know it works.

Comment: I finally got the time to test it and it works. Thank you!