# Missing OLE DB Provider for Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to link my vb.net program to a MS.ACCESS database to display my database to the crystal report, but I cant find the server in the OLE DB Provider.

I'm using:
Windows 8, 
Ms access 2013 and 
Microsoft visual studio 2008.

Comment: Are you accessing the database on the same machine?  Are you sure you have the correct driver?  What version of MS Access are you using?  What version of .NET Framework?

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: @JenniferS yes ma'am, am using ms access 2013 in my 64bit acer lappy,.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Sir, wat do u mean connection string? my initialization of my connection?

Comment: it's better if my reputation will go  up by 15 so i can post the screenshot,. i cant really explain clearly yet because i need to show the screenshot,. thanks for your answers, really appreciate it,.

Comment: It may be helpful to edit your question to include the code you're using to try to connect to the database

Comment: @RowlandShaw its not really in my code that's bothering me, my prob was in the procedure,. there was a missing provider Sir,. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

See this link and many more like it. [64 bit access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818491/is-there-a-64bit-driver-for-microsoft-access).  The standard jet driver is not available on 64 bit systems. But, you can download one.