# How do I connect to access database using java at runtime?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, connection, odbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Access over JDBC (using ODBC?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418807/accessing-access-over-jdbc-using-odbc)

I have to do this since we have an unknown amount of access databases the user can select using our program so as to process data from them.

Comment: @lost: There are many related questions comes rightside-bottom. Please check any of them..

Answer (score 0):

Here is connection code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=ACCESS_FILE_PATH/FILE_NAME.mdb";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"username","password");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as the following:

first , create a db DB1.MDB which contain a table named "table1";

second, config ODBC , create DatabaseSource named "Access2000"。

import java.sql.*;

```
    class database {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url="jdbc:odbc:Access2000";
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    String sql="SELECT * FROM table1";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    String tt;
    while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.print("name:" + rs.getString("Name"));
    System.out.println("age:" + rs.getString("Age"));
    }
    rs.close();
    connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
    System.exit(0);
    }
    }
    }
```